# Remove files and subdirectories of particular folder

Tags: rm

I need to remove files and sub-directories in a particular folder but not that folder itself.

I am using below command:

```
find . -type d -depth -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But it throws following error message:

> rm: refusing to remove ‘.’ or ‘..’ directory: skipping ‘.’

What should be the correct command I avoid or handle this error message? Is it happening because of option *"-depth"* in my *find* command?

Linux version:
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.1 (Maipo)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `/path/to/folder`, and would like to remove non-hidden files inside, but not that folder, just run:

```
rm -rf /path/to/folder/*
```

Note that this won't remove hidden files (ones starting with a dot).

And given that you have right permissions and don't need this folder on your system all the time, you can simply remove it and create a new empty folder:

```
rm -rf /path/to/folder; mkdir /path/to/folder
```

Comment: That won't remove filenames that start with "."

Comment: Agree with @ShadSterling. Plus: In folders with a lot of files you'll end up with a very long command line (`/path/to/folder/*` will be expanded by the shell to the list of all files in that directory). You may get a `command line too long` error in these cases.

Comment: @dasup Is that ever a problem in practice? On my current OS, ARG_MAX is 2097152. This means you could have 10k files in there that are 209 characters long. I believe that by the time it is possible for you to encounter this problem, you should have enough knowledge to know how to delete those, too.